# Is this され方 or され and ほう?

Tags: grammar

The sentence in question:
久宝まぶねこども園の五十嵐宏枝園長に話を聞いてみると、最近の子どもたちは、家でおんぶをしてもらうことが少なく、おんぶのされ方が分からないそうです。

For full context:
https://www3.nhk.or.jp/news/web_tokushu/2018_0521.html?utm_int=news_contents_tokushu_004

My attempt at translation:
"...when we asked for their story, it seemed that the children of the recent past, because at home they are rarely given piggbackrides, don't know the way of being taken on the back."

I interpreted され as the stem of the passive voice of する. Therefore I looked at され方 as a composition of され and ほう and came up with the above translation.
But since I basically just guessed at this, I wanted to ask for confirmation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Active Voice vs. Passive Voice***

する vs. される ("to do ~~" vs. "to be/get done ~~")

し方{かた} vs. され方{かた} ("how to do ~~" vs. "how to be/get done ~~")

Are you following me so far?

Active Voice: "Parents and older siblings おんぶ**する** babies".

Passive Voice: "Babies are おんぶ**される** by their parents and older siblings."

Thus, 「おんぶの**され方**が分{わ}からない」 means "(children) don't know ***how to be given*** piggyback rides."

So, your "understanding" is good except for the reading of 「方{かた}」 in 「され方」.